# Set environment variables in FLASK

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, terminal

The environment variables are cleared when you exit the terminal and it is required that we need to set them again when we launch the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

In vs code using bash in Ubuntu, if that is the case, look for setting the env variables in the .bash_profile so that it remembers the variables even after the terminal program is closed.

Comment: In the terminal you can paste this gedit  ~/.bash_profile command and add the environment variables

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `.env` file in order to handle environment configuration in Flask.

It's a file that stores all the necessary environment data and should be changed between development, production, etc.

There is an excellent tutorial about flask by Miguel Grinberg, the part about the environment is 
[here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xv-a-better-application-structure).